# What does `hookwrapper` mean for `py.test` hooks?

Tags: python, pytest

By looking at the documentation for `py.test` hooks [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#hooks) or [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#hookwrapper-executing-around-other-hooks) it is unclear to me what the expression `hookwrapper=True` means in the definition of a hook, for example:

```
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_pyfunc_call(pyfuncitem):
    do_something_before_next_hook_executes()

    outcome = yield
    # outcome.excinfo may be None or a (cls, val, tb) tuple

    res = outcome.get_result()  # will raise if outcome was exception

    post_process_result(res)

    outcome.force_result(new_res)  # to override the return value to the plugin system
```

What does it mean to define it with `hookwrapper=False`?

---

I came around this question as I created a hook in `conftest.py` for the hook `pytest_report_teststatus`, which only does work when I define the hook with `hookwrapper=False`:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=False)
def pytest_report_teststatus(report):
    return report.outcome, "letter", report.outcome.upper()
```

When using like that, the dot ('.') of a successful test is not written to the standard output.

Does it has something to do with generators?

I tried to redefine the same hook as follows:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_report_teststatus(report):
    yield report.outcome, "", report.outcome.upper()
```

using `hookwrapper=True`, but it did not change the outcome of the test (i.e. a dot '.' is printed nevertheless). So what does a `hookwrapper` mean?

**Bonus**: Why does the second implementation of the hook `pytest_report_teststatus` not work?